# My ajax for the edit button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my edit button in the modal in which the user may edit. However, the updating part is not working. I feel that the problem lies in my controller part but up to this point I can't seem to solve it on my own.

The response in the developers console for the ajax is (0) or when I use var_dump($data) from the controller the response is an array. I don't know whats going on. Can anyone help me? I've been doing this for almost 3 days. I was just skipping and going to another module. But I need to finish it now..

## Ajax code

```js
 $("#form2").submit(function(e) {

      var supp_code = $('#supp_codev1').val();
      var address1 = $('#address1v1').val();
      var address2 = $('#address2v1').val();
      var country = $('#countryv1').val();
      var description = $('#descriptionv1').val();
      var tel_num = $('#tel_numv1').val();
      var fax_num = $('#fax_numv1').val();
      var contact_person = $('#contact_personv1').val();
      var email = $('#emailv1').val();
      var consol_agent = $('#consol_agentv1').val();
      var disc1 = $('#disc1v1').val();
      var disc2 = $('#disc2v1').val();
      var disc3 = $('#disc3v1').val();
      var disc4 = $('#disc4v1').val();
      var disc5 = $('#disc5v1').val();
      var last_transaction = $('#last_transactionv1').val();
      var old_supplier = $('#old_supplierv1').val();

      var sfm_table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable();
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({


          url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>SFM/update',
          method: 'POST',
          dataType: 'JSON',

          data: {
              'supp_codev1': supp_code,
              'address1': address1,
              'address2': address2,
              'country': country,
              'description': description,
              'tel_num': tel_num,
              'fax_num': fax_num,
              'contact_person': contact_person,
              'email': email,
              'consol_agent': consol_agent,
              'disc1': disc1,
              'disc2': disc2,
              'disc3': disc3,
              'disc4': disc4,
              'disc5': disc5,
              'last_transaction': last_transaction,
              'old_supplier': old_supplier

          },



          success: function(data) {

              console.log(data);

              if (data) {

                  $("#sfm_modal_edit").modal('hide');

                  swal("Data Edited", {
                      icon: "success"
                  });


              } else {

                  swal("Error", {
                      icon: "error"
                  });
              }
          }
      });

  });
```

## Ajax for populating the form

```js
  $(document).on("click", ".editBtn", function() {

      var rowID = $(this).attr('id');

      $.ajax({
          url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>SFM/fetch',

          method: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
              'id': rowID
          },

          success: function(data) {

             


              $('#supp_codev1').val(data.fo_supp[0].SUPP_CODE);
              $('#address1v1').val(data.fo_supp[0].ADDRESS);
              $('#address2v1').val(data.fo_supp[0].ADDRESS2);
              $('#countryv1').val(data.fo_supp[0].COUNTRY);
              $('#descriptionv1').val(data.fo_supp[0].DESCRIPTION);
              $('#tel_numv1').val(data.fo_supp[0].TEL_NO);
              $('#fax_numv1').val(data.fo_supp[0].FAX_NO);
              $('#contact_personv1').val(data.fo_supp[0].CONTACT);
              $('#emailv1').val(data.fo_supp[0].EMAIL);
              $('#consol_agentv1').val(data.fo_supp[0].CONS_AGENT);
              $('#disc1v1').val(data.fo_supp[0].DISC1);
              $('#disc2v1').val(data.fo_supp[0].DISC2);
              $('#disc3v1').val(data.fo_supp[0].DISC3);
              $('#disc4v1').val(data.fo_supp[0].DISC4);
              $('#disc5v1').val(data.fo_supp[0].DISC5);
              $('#last_transactionv1').val(data.fo_supp[0].LAST_TRANS);
              $('#old_supplierv1').val(data.fo_supp[0].SUPP_CODE2);




          }
      });

  });
```

## Controller

```js
 function update()
 {
   $data = array(
    'SUPP_CODE'=> $this->input->post('supp_codev1'),
       'ADDRESS'=> $this->input->post('address1'),
       'ADDRESS2'=> $this->input->post('address2'),
       'COUNTRY'=> $this->input->post('country'),
       'DESCRIPTION'=> $this->input>post('description'),
       'TEL_NO'=> $this->input->post('tel_num'),
       'FAX_NO'=> $this->input->post('fax_num'),
       'CONTACT'=> $this->input->post('contact_person'),
       'EMAIL'=> $this->input->post('email'),
       'CONS_AGENT'=> $this->input>post('consol_agent'),
       'DISC1'=> $this->input->post('disc1'),
       'DISC2'=> $this->input->post('disc2'),
       'DISC3'=> $this->input->post('disc3'),
       'DISC4'=> $this->input->post('disc4'),
       'DISC5'=> $this->input->post('disc5'),
       'LAST_TRANS'=> $this->input- >post('last_transaction'),
       'SUPP_CODE2'=> $this->input->post('old_supplier')
     );

     $supp =  $this->input->post('supp_codev1');

     $insertReturn2 = $this->system_model->update('fo_supp', $supp ,$data);

  echo json_encode($insertReturn2);

 }
```

## View

```html
 <!--MODAL HERE-->
        <div class="modal fade" name="sfm_modal_edit " id="sfm_modal_edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
       <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            Edit Supplier
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal Body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="form2" class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                <!-- left column -->
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Supplier Code</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Supplier Code</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="supp_codev1" id="supp_codev1" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'mask': '999999'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Address</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Address</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="address1v1" class="form-control  col-md-10" id="address1v1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_address" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Address 2</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Address 2</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="address2v1" class="form-control  col-md-10" id="address2v1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Country</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Country</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="countryv1" id="countryv1" class="form-control col-md-10" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <div class="form-group"><label for="new_zip" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style = "visibility: hidden;">Description</label><span class="label label-default" >Supplier Code</span><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_zip" placeholder=""></div><div class="col-sm-7"><label for="new_zip_detail" class="sr-only" style = "visibility: hidden;">City, State Country</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_zip_detail" placeholder="City, State Country" disabled=""></div></div> -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Description</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Description</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="descriptionv1" class="form-control" id="descriptionv1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Telephone Number</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Telephone Number</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel_numv1" id="tel_numv1" data-inputmask="'mask' : '(999) 999-9999'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Fax Number</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Fax Number</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fax_numv1" id="fax_numv1" data-inputmask="'mask' : '(999) 999-9999'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Consolidating Agent</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Consolidating Agent</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="consol_agentv1" class="form-control" id="consol_agentv1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 
                                </div>
                                <!-- right column -->
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Email</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Email</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailv1" id="emailv1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Contact Person</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Contact Person</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_personv1" id="contact_personv1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 1</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 1</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc1v1" id="disc1v1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_address" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 2</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 2</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc2v1" id="disc2v1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 3</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 3</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc3v1" id="disc3v1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 4</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 4</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="disc4v1" id="disc4v1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 5</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 5</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="disc5v1" id="disc5v1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Last Transaction</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Last Transaction</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_transactionv1" id="last_transactionv1" data-inputmask="'mask': '9999/99/99'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Old Supplier</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Old Supplier</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="old_supplierv1" id="old_supplierv1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                    </div>
                    <!-- End main input boxes, starting a new "row" -->
                    <!-- Modal Footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Modal Footer -->
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- End modal body div -->
            </div>
            <!-- End modal content div -->
        </div>
        <!-- End modal dialog div -->
    </div>
    <!-- End modal div -->
```

Answer (score 0):

object class named "editBtn" not found

do you create "editBtn" object in document?

Comment: Yes, In the action rows of the table.

Comment: I used that for the fetching part. The first ajax where $("#form2").submit(function(e) ) doesn't work or error occurs

Comment: what about you move to back "e.preventDefault();" after ajax call $.ajax({...}) e.preventDefault();

Comment: are you clear put $("#form2").submit() in $(document).ready()?

Comment: Could you please check my controller and see if it's correct?

Comment: I don't know well php but I'm sure about that js function doesn't work is js problem